# Puzzling Proof Involving IVT

Tags: calculus

If a and b are positive numbers, prove that the equation

$$ \frac{a}{x^3+2x-1} + \frac{b}{x^3+x-2}=0$$

has at least one solution in the interval $(-1,1)$.

You can't plug and chug because you'll wind up with an undefined term for both numbers terminating the given interval.  We do know that if c exists, at $f(c)$, $x^3 + 2x - 1$ and $x^3 + x - 2$ evaluate to numbers of opposite sign AND that the two terms are equal; otherwise two numbers with positive numerators a and b would not add to zero.  And if we assume that c does exist, then $f(-1) < f(0) < f(1)$.

If this is the case, then, for $f(-1)$, the term which evaluates to a greater value must be negative.  Similarly, for $f(1)$, either both terms are positive or the term which evaluates to a greater value must be positive.

I'm sorta groping in the dark here, collecting information but unsure of how to apply it to prove the original assertion.

Answer (score 4):

Your equation is equivalent to:
$$f(x)=\frac{x^3+2x-1}{x^3+x-2}=-\frac{a}{b}.$$
Notice that $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[-1,1)$, and since $f(-1)=1$ while $$\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=-\infty,$$
$f(x)$ takes any value in $[0,-\infty)$ over $I=[-1,1)$.

Additionally, $f(x)$ is decreasing over $I$, hence the solution is unique.

Comment: You're brilliant dude.  Assuming the first term was greater than zero, and thus the second less than zero, I set up an equation using this information, then used the cubic formula to solve for c.  Your solution is far more elegant.  I hope to attain your level of mathematical maturity at some point.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually, wait a second.  The exponent attached to the highest terms in both the numerator and denominator are both 3.  Beautiful solution, wrong problem.

Comment: @akuryo: Yes, it is intended to be a three, it was just a typo.

Comment: Just curious:  what would you do if the term 2x was 2x^2?

Comment: In such a case, $f(0)=1/2,f(1^-)=-\infty$, hence $f(x)$ would take any value in $(-\infty,1/2]$.

Comment: However, in such a case the solution may not be unique, since $1/2$ is not the greatest value took by $f$ on $[-1,1)$.

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't understand f(1-) = - infinity.  Will you explain?  How do you substitute 1 from the left?

Comment: It was just a shorcut notation for $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: Oh I see.  Please excuse all of these questions; I just have a few more.  Did you know intuitively that f(1-) = - infinity, or did you make a table of values?  If you did know intuitively, will you share your intuition?

Comment: @akuryo: $1$ is a zero of the denominator, that is negative in a left neighbourhood of $1$. The numerator is positive in a whole neighbourhood of $1$. This gives that the limit of the ratio when $x$ approaches $1^-$ is $-\infty$.

Comment: Ahhhh.  You have been of great assistance to me.  One more question:  I am in first-year calculus in America, and the book they assign (Stewart) is awful.  Its explanations are superficial and the exercises don't test intuition, but rote memorization of formulas.  I am considering studying Apostol on the side.  Wise choice?

Comment: @akuryo: I'm on your side ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hints

1. $a,b$ are both positive.
2. Each of the cubics has a real root in the interval $[0,1]$.
3. In fact it is easy to see that one must be less than the other.

Comment: I don't understand this at all.

Comment: @TonyK To go a bit further ... One cubic has a root near 0.5, the other has a root at 1. So when you take the reciprocals they go to $\infty$ there. Now look at signs, specifically between the two roots.